# HTTPS 443 port: netstat shows wildcard but curl --insecure only works for localhost

Tags: https, port

I have a remote machine with public IP address `121.x.y.z`, with Gitlab (the software does not really matter and Gitlab knowledge is not required here) installed (which uses nginx for its web interface) and HTTPS setup. However I am in a situation where I can only access through HTTPS using localhost but no other IP address.

When I do `netstat -an | grep 443` in the remote machine I get

```
[user@machine ~]$ netstat -an | grep 443
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

When I do `curl --insecure https://127.0.0.1` in the remote machine I get

```
[user@machine ~]$ curl --insecure https://127.0.0.1
<html><body>You are being <a href="https://127.0.0.1/users/sign_in">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

The redirected message is the default correct message with Gitlab.

However when I do `curl --insecure https://121.x.y.z` in the remote machine I get nothing but infinite waiting time (seems like it is not actually listening). But netstat result seems to indicate it is listening to all ip addresses, not just localhost.

The Gitlab web interface works correctly if I discard HTTPS settings and go back to HTTP.

I don't know how to even proceed debugging this issue and is pretty much stuck. Is there anything I can do to figure out why it only listens to localhost while netstat shows it listens to everything?

Edit:
The system is CentOS7 and firewalld seems to be not active too.

```
[user@machine ~]$ sudo systemctl status firewalld
● firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:firewalld(1)

Aug 14 10:55:45 xxxxxx systemd[1]: firewalld.service: Unit cannot be reloaded because it is inactive.
```

Comment: A timeout usually points toward a firewall issue.

Comment: I also included `sudo systemctl status firewalld` result and it seems not active. Is there any other possible firewall on centOS7?

Comment: The firewall can be anywhere between you and the remote machine. Since you provide no information about the infrastructure we can't even guess.

Comment: The curl commands are all executed in the remote machine ssh terminal

Comment: When the public IP-address  is not configured on the machine itself (which is typically the case for floating IP-addresses and similar constructs in cloud environments (check for example with `ip addr` ) traffic from the instance to that public IP-address is also subject to external access controls  such as security groups. Those access controls are not enforced with a local firewall (iptables, firewalld, ufw or similar) and not immediately apparent.

Comment: @Bob Thank you so much. It looks like the IP address issue is exactly the problem. The cloud service I am using seems to have server instance and ip addresses handled separately